# JSON.net deserialize date with javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, serialization, json.net

When I serialize a date using Json.Net I get the date formatted as:

```
'2015-07-07T17:27:00.057'
```

once I receive that object from ajax it comes as a string not as a date. How can I convert '2015-07-07T17:27:00.057' to a javascript date.

I have tried

```
 new Date('2015-07-07T17:27:00.057') but that gives the incorrect date
```

---

### Edit:

Found the problem. If I serialize `DateTime.Now` I get the wrong date. But if I serialize `DateTime.UtcNow` I get the correct date when deserializing. I need to save my dates in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). The comments were the solution, thanks so much.

Comment: Usually, when a timezone is not specified, the computer system assumes GMT.   For example, when I type that line into my browsers console, the date is July 7, 2015 11:27:00. Notice that the the JSON time is 17:27, but my browser interprets it as 11:27 because I am -6 from GMT.

Comment: Are you using e.g. DateTime.Now rather than DateTime.UtcNow? Timezones matter, your serialized value has a T in, rather than Z for universal time. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Yes I think that is the problem. I am using dateTime.Now :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json.Net supports multiple ways of formatting a date, if your only consuming it from an ajax call you may want to look into JavaScriptDateTimeConverter.

http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DatesInJSON.htm

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need the timezone information encoded in the string. Try using [DateTimeOffset.Now](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.now(v=vs.110).aspx) for a portable time format.

Also check out:

- [Can you tell JSON.Net to serialize DateTime as Utc even if unspecified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302902/can-you-tell-json-net-to-serialize-datetime-as-utc-even-if-unspecified)
- http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateTimeZoneHandling.htm

Answer (score -1):

try

```
new Date(JSON.parse(datestr));
```