# Gson parse time without time zone indicator?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am trying to deserialise a MyClass object with Gson. MyClass has a `DateTime` field in C#, but the same field is in `Date` type in Java. The object was serialised by Json.NET.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(myReader, MyClass.class);
```

This caused an exception.

```
java.text.ParseException: Failed to parse date ["2016-11-05T14:23:00']: No time zone indicator (at offset 0)
```

Apparently, Json.NET has serialised a DateTime field as `"2016-11-05T14:23:00"` and Gson thinks it is a wrong format because it lacks time zone. Is there any way to tell Gson to just assume current time zone of the system rather than throwing an exception? I am looking for an easy way to solve this situation other than writing a complete custom class adapter myself.

Comment: Assuming the time zone of the system sounds like a very bad move to me - you'd end up with a `Date` which could represent an entirely different point in time from what your server meant. What does the value actually represent - is it a) a time in a particular time zone; b) an instant in time; c) a local time in no particular time zone? Those should be represented differently in JSON IMO, and you should make both your Java and .NET code reflect the difference too.

Comment: Easiest way would be to take it as a `String` and deal with the `Date` parsing in your code rather than leave it to `GSON`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. If there is no simple way, I think I will modify the Json.NET to [use UTC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302902/can-you-tell-json-net-to-serialize-datetime-as-utc-even-if-unspecified) instead.

Comment: *"Is there any way to tell Gson?"* Yes, using `@JsonAdapter`.