# What's the best practice about receiving DateTime input through the View Models?

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a View Model, where one of the properties is `DateTime`. I want to allow the requester to send a DateTime in any timezone they want to. On my end, I want to convert that date-time to UTC and if timezone information did not arrive with the date, to just assume it's UTC.

Alternatively, I'd be fine with restricting the posted `DateTime` to either UTC or to at least something that contains timezone information.

My backend works with all dates in UTC, returns them in UTC and that's how it saves too. This question is about receiving the 'client' input and what's the best practice of accepting the date and turning it into or ensuring it's UTC.

This is what I have right now

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Start date, in UTC.
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

And in the Controller:

```
// Convert to UTC
model.StartDate = model.StartDate.ToUniversalTime();
```

I guess I could also do that in the View Model itself, by adding a constructor.

What's the best practice about receiving `DateTime` input through the View Models? Ultimately I want to ensure what I receive is UTC.

Comment: It really depends on a project by project basis. Providing you are consistent in your approach I have seen it done in various ways and what you're doing is fine.

Comment: The global setting [`DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DateTimeZoneHandling.htm).  may be what you need.  It converts to UTC during deserialization taking into account any explicit time zone offsets in the JSON datetime string.

Comment: @dbc "taking into account any explicit time zone offsets in the JSON datetime string" - 
meaning if there's a timezone in the string, it won't override it, right?

Comment: Meaning that it will use the time zone in the string to convert to UTC, taking the provided time zone into account.  See [Can you tell JSON.Net to serialize DateTime as Utc even if unspecified?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10302902/3744182) Alternatively I suppose you could make a synthetic `DateTimeOffset` property in your model and do the conversion yourself in the setter.

Comment: Can you please clarify: 1) Is this ASP.Net or ASP.Net Core? 2) Is this model used in a REST API Controller (receiving JSON)? Or is it a View Model used with a Razor MVC View (receiving form-post values)?  3) Are you sending whole dates (like `2019-03-20`) or date+time values (like `2019-03-20T00:00:00`) or date+time+offset values (like `2019-03-20T00:00:00-08:00`)?

Comment: One point to make right away: `DateTime.ToUniversalTime` should *never* be used in a web app.  It converts *from the server's local time zone* to UTC.

Comment: @MattJohnson, it's Web API 2 (not Core). Yes, it's a REST controller which receives JSON. It receives date+time, but I may have other use cases where I receive just the date. Thanks for the second point, I was going in the wrong direction then. I think `DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc` gives me what I need - an input in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is to be used in multiple timezones, I would suggest to save UTC datetime object in database.

A common practice to convert this UTC date time object to local datetime.

**Intput**

API should take ISO 8601 format as input [as mentioned in this blog](https://www.moesif.com/blog/technical/timestamp/manage-datetime-timestamp-timezones-in-api/#).

> prefer ISO 8601 (yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ) because it’s
>   human readable and has a specified timezone. There is no ambiguity if
>   the epoch is in seconds or milliseconds. ISO 8601 strings are encoded
>   in a way that enable decent string sorting and comparison.

**Output**

I believe you want to know how should web api return the DateTime object.

In my opinion, RESTful API should be independent of timezone and it should return date in UTC.

The phone app / desktop app / web app which is calling this API should have responsibility to show dates in correct timezone format.

But again, as stated earlier in the comments, this decision is driven by design of your application.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, I already save the dates as UTC and by virtue I also always return UTC. I agree, it shall be up to the consumer to show it in the right timezone. The question is about the *input*. What's the best practice to either ensure that the date comes as UTC.